# Does this quiz question make sense?

Tags: grammaticality

> I want to buy ____ books, two for my brother and the other for me.
>
> A. all   ;      B. both  ;    C. three

I encountered this question in a quiz today. I choose answer C, but the answer key is A. I don't understand why. To me, the question itself doesn't make sense. First, I doubt the use of "the other". If the answer was A, then it should be *the other**s** for me*. Also, "buy all books" doesn't sound quite right. "All the books" seems to make much more sense. Second, if I go for answer C, the structure "two ... the other" confuses me. Usually, I'd expect "one ... the other".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Who wrote this quiz question? This is outrageous!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible answers are:

> A: I want to buy **all** books, two for my brother and the other for me.
>
> B: I want to buy **both** books, two for my brother and the other for me.
>
> C: I want to buy **three** books, two for my brother and the other for me.

You are correct that with A it should be "all *the* books", not just "all books". Although you could say "the others" (plural) afterwards, you'd probably be more likely to say "the rest":

> A: I want to buy **all the** books, two for my brother and the **others** for me.
>
> A: I want to buy **all the** books, two for my brother and the **rest** for me.

"the others" is more likely to be used for a small number, and "the rest" is more likely to be used for a large number. "all" implies a lot, which is why I say "the rest" would be more common. However, with the right context it could be as few as three:

> Which book do you want to buy? The Cat in the Hat, The Little Prince, or The Very Hungry Caterpillar?
>
> I'll buy **all** the books.
>
> I'll buy **all** these books.
>
> I'll buy **all** of these books.
>
> I'll buy **all** of them.

With B it is grammatically correct but doesn't make sense since "both" is always two, so there  would be no "other" for yourself.

With C it is both grammatically correct and makes sense. What is probably confusing you is the use of "other" as a pronoun. In this sentence it has the same meaning as "other one" or "other book".

> C1: I want to buy **three** books, two for my brother and the **other** for me.
>
> C2: I want to buy **three** books, two for my brother and the **other one** for me.
>
> C3: I want to buy **three** books, two for my brother and the **other book** for me.

C1 and C2 sound the best. C3 is a little awkward because of the repetition of "book".

There is no grammatical difference between "one book for X and the other for Y" and "two books for X and the other for Y". It's just more common to have a division of two objects than three so you would have encountered it more often.

So the quiz is wrong. The best answer is C, not A.

Answer (score 1):

You've kind of answered your own question - answer 'A' doesn't fit without changing the question. If you have to change the question to make your answer correct, then your answer is wrong.

"The other" can only refer to **one** book, because of the definite article and the singular "other". So if there are **two** books for your brother plus **one** for you, that makes **three**.

> I want to buy **three** books - **two** for my brother and **the other** for me.

*Mathematically* the answer has to be three. But from an English grammar point of view "*I want to buy all books*" is just not grammatical, so it can't be correct.

The answer to the question (as written) can only be **C**.

Comment: So you think answer C is correct without having to change the question itself? I feel "two ... the other" strange. Maybe, "the other one for me" is better?

Comment: @dan Yeah, I think C sounds fine without changing anything else.

Comment: @dan Yes - if you've read the question correctly and it is as written in your post, the answer can only be 'C' - "three". It doesn't matter that "brother" is singular - the answer is the number of books, so all you need to count is the 2+1. But that's the mathematical side of it - I want to buy *all* books" is not grammatical in this context.

Comment: @Astralbee, If I understand correctly, "buy all books" sounds like *buying all kinds of books in the world*. Right?